# Exporting menu structure using services

Tags: routes, services

Is it possible to to export the menu structure of my drupal site using the services module? This way the website structure can be generated on the drupal website -> make it available for webservices -> acces by mobile in order to build the same structure dynamically in the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

The [Menu API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu/7) is fairly extensive.  It is likely there is already a function available to return what you need.

For example, you can return an entire menu tree using the [menu_tree_all_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7)().

```
$navigation_tree = menu_tree_all_data('navigation');
```

You could also return everything known to the menu router with [menu_get_router](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_router/7)();

```
$everything = menu_get_router();
```